# Components won't show on Frame Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to make a message box with a label and a button. At first I tried witohout "BorderLayout.." there and I set bounds for every component. But my JLabel appeared on the screen "Puzzle....", and the width dimension was enough big.
Now I tried with this method but I have nothing in my JFrame. It looks like this:

[image]

I resolved this with JOptionPaneMessage, but I just want to know what was wrong at my code. I use this just for learning purpose.

Here is the code:

```
JFrame a = new JFrame("Message");
        JLabel mesaj = new JLabel("Puzzle cannot be solved!");
        JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
        a.add(mesaj, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        a.add(ok, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        a.setSize(450, 200);
        a.isFocusableWindow();
        a.setLayout(null);  
        a.setVisible(true);  
        a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: It's because of this line: `a.setLayout(null);`. When you use null layout (you shouldn't), you have to set the bounds of components. Please read through [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for further information on how to use layout managers.

Comment: Remove `a.setLayout(null);` , because this replaces the default layout manager which is `BorderLayout` for a JFrame's content panel.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand. With that command I made the layout null so I could put my components using bounds, because the frame was null. But at this I didn't used bound, I set the layout on, and then I removed it, so there is nothing... Thx, this have sense